# Removing redundancy when adding items to Python dictionaries

Tags: python

Suppose you have a dictionary like:

```
my_dict = {'foo' : {'bar' : {}}}
```

And you want to make the following sequence of assignments:

```
my_dict['foo']['bar']['first'] = 1
my_dict['foo']['bar']['second'] = 2
```

Clearly there is some redundancy in the fact that `my_dict['foo']['bar']` is repeated. Is there any way to prevent this redundancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Not really, save of course the obvious intermediate variable:

```
foo_bar = my_dict['foo']['bar']
foo_bar['first'] = 1
foo_bar['second'] = 2
```

How is Python supposed to know you want to refer to the same dictionary twice unless you tell it like this?

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
my_dict['foo']['bar'].update({'first': 1, 'second': 2})
```

Answer (score 3):

you could hold it in a temporary:

```
temp = my_dict['foo']['bar']
temp['first'] = 1
temp['second'] = 1
```

or you could use update:

```
my_dict['foo']['bar'].update([('first', 1), ('second', 2)])
```

or there are other options.